# Make Javascript regular expression case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using a jquery function I found to find words in a div and highlight them.  I'm using this along with a search tool so the case is not always going to match the words exactly.  How can I convert this to make it case insensitive?

```
$.fn.highlight = function(what,spanClass) {
    return this.each(function(){
        var container = this,
            content = container.innerHTML,
            pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + what + ')([^<.]*)','g'),
            replaceWith = '$1<span ' + ( spanClass ? 'class="' + spanClass + '"' : '' ) + '">$2</span>$3',
            highlighted = content.replace(pattern,replaceWith);
        container.innerHTML = highlighted;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + what + ')([^<.]*)','gi')
```

[add the 'i' flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to make it case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Just add the 'i' flag.

```
pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + what + ')([^<.]*)','gi')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.highlight = function(what,spanClass) {
return this.each(function(){
    var container = this,
        content = container.innerHTML,
        pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + what + ')([^<.]*)','gi'),
        replaceWith = '$1<span ' + ( spanClass ? 'class="' + spanClass + '"' : '' ) + '">$2</span>$3',
        highlighted = content.replace(pattern,replaceWith);
    container.innerHTML = highlighted;
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just add "i":

```
pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + what + ')([^<.]*)','gi'),
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> Regular expressions have four optional flags that allow for global and
>   case insensitive searching. To indicate a global search, use the g
>   flag. To indicate a case-insensitive search, use the i flag. To
>   indicate a multi-line search, use the m flag. To perform a "sticky"
>   search, that matches starting at the current position in the target
>   string, use the y flag. These flags can be used separately or together
>   in any order, and are included as part of the regular expression.